# Drawing Layers over ImageView in Android

Tags: android, drawing, layer, undo, redo

Can anyone guide me how can I put different drawing layers on an Image which is shown over ImageView component. 
Basically I want to implement Undo and Redo Functionality in my drawing application.

Currently I can put text or Drawing over image but can't achieve Undo/Redo functionality. I wonder this can be possible by maintaining some layering stuff.

Plz help me out.

this is my current drawing code..

```
    try {

        image.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = image.getDrawingCache();

        try

        {

            bitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, image.getHeight(),
                    image.getWidth());

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 1)
                    .show();
        }

        TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
        tp.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        tp.setAntiAlias(true);
        tp.setTextSize(30);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawText(input.getText().toString(), xPos, yPos, tp);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        input.setText("");
        input.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 1).show();
    }
```

thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done it in another way.
Create orignal bitmap and save it in some bitmap variable. Now on every onDraw call initiate a bitmap with orignal one and pass it to canvas. Then do what you want to do..

Comment: It's been ages now, I will look for code and will help you if found.

Comment: I have implemented what you have explained. No need for you to search for  your code. Thanks alot, tried to implement undo with image,text and path for quiet some time. finally done it.

Comment: Thanks something nice...

What I remember from that code is like to maintain a stack of drawing operations in a couple of lists and simply push pop  items...

Answer (score 0):

Try LayerDrawable from Android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList